# How to create empty Zip folder in asp.net1.1

Tags: asp.net, zip

I'am doing upload functionality in ASP.NET 1.1.
I want to create one empty zip folder on given path.

So, how to create an empty zip folder?

Later on I will save files in that folder. I do not want to use any third party component.

Comment: why do you want this in .NET 1.1? at least .NET 3.5 no? there are so many advantages, even for using compressing formats

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of third-party components that do this.  Writing one from scratch would be a big effort, I do not recommend it.  Why the requirement not to use an existing library? There are some suggested in the answers for [Open-source zip library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374396/open-source-zip-library-for-net).

If all you really want is an empty zip file, simply add one to your solution and copy it into place as necessary.

Comment: Thanx for your Reply...I dnt want add this empty folder ...it should get addedd automaticaly at run time..which are thrid party component..? how to use that.

Comment: +1 for "simply copy an existing empty zip file". (I also edited in the link from the comment.)