# How to zip/unzip files without 3rd party vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip

Is there any code for vb.net so i can zip and unzip file without any 3rd party programs. 
e.g. (i know this is  not right)

```
 Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    zip.AddDirectory(directory)
    zip.Save(targetZip)
End Using
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open-source zip library for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374396/open-source-zip-library-for-net)

Answer (score 1):

There's the [ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) class in .NET but it is such a PITA to use that you are probably better of using a third party library such as [SharpZipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx).

Comment: I am still confused to how it works

Comment: @Kuzon, it is pretty well documented. Is there some part of the documentation that you are confused with? Or some specific example that you try to implement and that didn't work?

Comment: How do i use SharpZibLib with vb.net... sorry I am still quite new to programming...