# how to zip stream?

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

I am reading/writing a stream file in C# (.Net 1.1).  My file's size is too large and I want compress that to a zip file and save this zip file.

How can I compress my the file?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here are several links that can help you(1 minute of googling):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

[MSDN watch at the bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks dear friend. it was so useful. thanks <3

Comment: I want vote up your answer, but I have 9 reputation :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

There are some third party controllers for this.

For the time you can refer following link to get more guidance regarding zipping in .net1.1

[Open-source zip library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374396/open-source-zip-library-for-net)